# iOS- Build failed due to obsolete method names in pod dependency files

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I was trying to make a demo project which uses a POD dependency of this URL [PageMenu](https://github.com/PageMenu/PageMenu) POD install correctly but gives me many errors on building this dummy app as many methods' are renamed in latest iOS SDK and swift 4.2. I have solved this problem before on my office project but can't remember right now. Any help will be appreciable. I am attaching a screenshot with this project. 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reasons for the problem:** Swift version of my project is 4.2 and I am using a library which was built in swift version 4. So some of the method's name in latest iOS SDK is renamed from Swift 4.

**Solution:** I need to set Swift version 4 for that pod dependency and recompile this project.

**Note:** Any third party pod that doesn't support the latest swift must be compiled with the supported version of swift for pod dependency

Comment: How do you do this?

Comment: @MetaSnarf You mean setting the swift version?